# tufte-book doesn't work with autonum

Tags: tufte, autonum

the following gives me an error

```
    \documentclass{tufte-book}

    \usepackage{autonum}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
      1=1 \label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

I get the error

```
   Runaway argument?
   \@nolnerr \fi 
   ! Paragraph ended before \llm@CarThree was complete.
    <to be read again> 
                       \par 
     l.6 \begin{equation}
```

When I comment out the line loading autonum, all is well --- except I do not get the benefits of autonum.

I add that using the standard `book` class with autonum, I get no errors.

Help appreciated

Comment: See also https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/issues/121